# Can't get user location using Google Play Services API Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have been trying to work with `Google Play Services` in my android app to get the user location but the `MapsActivity` seems not to update the location. I have tried out three tutorials but none of them seems to solve the issue of getting the user's location.

MapsActivity.java

```
package com.whitewebteam.deliverus;

import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

private GoogleMap map;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    if (googleApiClient == null) {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10000)        
            .setFastestInterval(1000); 
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(0, 0);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Location services connected.");
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
    if (lastLocation == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }
    else {
        handleNewLocation(lastLocation);
    }
}

private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("I am here!");
    map.addMarker(options);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Location services suspended. Please reconnect.");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    handleNewLocation(location);
}
}
```

I have also added location access to my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

and added the following dependencies in `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
```

I had changed the dependencies from:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
```

but it didn't solve the issue. The `MapsActivity` sticks to the default `LatLag(0,0)`. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you debug what do you get here in the onConnected method Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

Comment: no am not getting any errors. yes, am running a marshmallow emulator

Comment: are you getting a warning in console that you are not asking for runtime permission?

Comment: no, i am not getting any warning

Comment: When you debug what do you get at that line? Is that line returning (0,0) before passing it to the handleNewLocation method?

Comment: it says `I/MapsActivity: Location services connected.` I can't seem to get what it returns before passing to handleNewLocation. I have added a log to check if `lastLocation` is null or otherwise log `lastLocation.toString()` but nothing is being logged